# IAB.close() called but is was already closed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Ionic App loop in splashscreen

console error

> IAB.close() called but is was already closed in TypeScript

follow same erros and change info to trust *(NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads)*

but not works

EDIT : *gap* Security Policy considerer unsafe

update index.html and solved

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;">
```

Comment: Could you explain the components of that `Content-Security-Policy` please?